# How to build a demon hunter?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I've got a level 14 Drow Rogue built around hand crossbows. I want to modify him to be a Demon Hunter. How can I accomplish this using feats, items and paragon paths, without losing the hide-and-shoot nature that I've already established?

To qualify as a demon hunter, I am looking for items or powers that do special things or extra damage to targets with the demon keyword. I am willing to sacrifice my "normal" accuracy and damage to reach this goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feat Corellon's Wrath Style [<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1298) will upgrade riposte strike to deal extra Int damage to demons, though that is a light blade attack not a crossbow attack.

The feat Demonbane [<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1509) allows divine attacks that target undead to also target creatures with the elemental origin (which includes demons). If you multi-class to Cleric using the Channel of Faith multi class feat [<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1622) you gain the turn undead power. Likewise Channel of Vengence multi class feat [<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1625) will get you the Avenger variant.

Demonbane weapons[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1419) grant you

> Property: On a critical hit you deal +2d10 damage instead of +2d8 against demons.
>
> Power (Daily): Free Action. Use this power when you attack a demon with this weapon. Gain a +5 power bonus to the attack roll and ignore any resist value the demon has.

Demon slayer weapons[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3757) grant you

> Property: On a critical hit you deal +2d12 damage instead of +2d8 against demons.
>
> Power (At-Will): Free Action. Use this power when you hit a creature that has the demon keyword with this weapon. The demon does not benefit from variable resistance until the start of your next turn.
>
> Power (Daily): Minor Action. Your next attack with this weapon against a demon, if made before the end of your next turn, gains a +5 power bonus to the attack roll.